# Cancel upload on AjaxUpload at onSubmit

Tags: javascript, ajax-upload

is it possible to cancel AjaxUpload during OnSubmit, for example:

```
var file_uploader = new window.AjaxUpload(
        'wall-file-upload',
        { action: 'attach_something',
            name: 'userfile',
            onSubmit: function(file,ext) { if(something){cancel_upload();} },        
        }
    );
```

So cancel upload is executed at onSubmit. Is this possible?

Comment: provide some more relevant code, and describe it in brief

Comment: is the upload is triggered via a AJAX ?

Comment: @AnirbanN,  AjaxUpload is a javascript plugin http://zurb.com/playground/ajax-upload. And this question is addressed to their developers

Answer (score 0):

You can use abort() function on jQuery ajax object, but you have to understand, that the request will be processed by the server anyway.

Comment: abort function must be called by an Ajax object. Can I file_uploader?

Comment: Well, I need a source of AjaxUpload class to tell you how exactly it must be implemented, if you don't understand how it works

Comment: Hmmm... From the source code.
`
            // Callback to fire before file is uploaded
            // You can return false to cancel upload
            onSubmit: function(file, extension){
            }
`

So just `return false;` in your onSubmit function and that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this casze you can try aborting your upload via `xhr.abort()`, So try

```
var file_uploader = new window.AjaxUpload(
        'wall-file-upload',
        { action: 'attach_something',
            name: 'userfile',
            onSubmit: function(file,ext) { if(something){xhr.abort();} },        
        }
    );
```

Comment: hmm... I don't have xhr created anywhere... sure this is working?